# C# Executing a method with intervals using system.threading.timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, execute, intervals

Hello
Lets say I have a console application, that looks like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

}

I wan't to execute my DoSomething method every 10'th second by using System.Threading.timer. Can anyone give an example of how that is done?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer(10000);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
        timer1.Start();



    static void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Do Something

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation page for the `System.Threading.Timer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx#Y2101) has a lengthy, good example.